# Bad font anti-aliasing in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, anti-aliasing, fontconfig

I'm switching from Fedora 8 to Ubuntu 9.04, and I can't seem to get it to get a good font anti-aliasing to work. It seems that Ubuntu's fontconfig tries to keep characters in integral pixel widths. This makes text more difficult to read, when 1 pixel is too thin and 2 pixels is too thick.

Check the image below. In Fedora, when fontconfig anti-aliasing is enabled, fonts have their thickness proportional to the font size. Below, the thickness is different for 8, 9 and 10pt sizes. In Ubuntu, on the other hand, even when anti-aliasing is enabled, all 8, 9 and 10pt sizes have 1 pixel thickness. This makes reading larges amount of text difficult.

[image: Comparing Fedora 8 and Ubuntu 9.04 font anti-aliasing.]

I'm using the very same home directory, and I already checked that X resources are the same in both systems:

```
~% xrdb -query | grep Xft
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
Xft.rgba:       none
```

GNOME settings:

```
~% gconftool-2 -a /desktop/gnome/font_rendering
 antialiasing = grayscale
 hinting = full
 dpi = 96
 rgba_order = rgb
```

So, the question is: What should I change in the new box (Ubuntu) in order to get anti-aliasing like in the old box (Fedora)?

Comment: Is it just me who thinks that the Ubuntu fonts are much sharper and readable than the Fedora fonts? The Fedora fonts look way too blurry IMHO.

Comment: I actually like the one on the right more. The one on the left is way too blurry. To each his own, though. ;)

Comment: @Yaba: Obviously not... You beat me by 17 seconds. :)

Comment: @Yaba, @musicfreak: If you have CRT monitors or have a low resolution, the ones on the left may look too blurry. Otherwise, they better reflect the size of the font. Look at how the thickness of the lines in the right image suddenly jump from 1px to 3px as you increase the font size. This is also bad when it is being projected. The text doesn't become more readable as you increase the font size until it is too big (when it jumps to 3px).

Comment: Also, in the Ubuntu sample, look at how there is a missing pixel in the "k" in "quick" in the third text line, making it look like it was two glyphs, a "|" and a "<".

Comment: @Juliano

Then I have the first available Laptop with a built in CRT monitor :-)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is an old trick to make fonts smoother on Ubuntu (and pretty much every distro running Gnome):

Open up .fonts.conf under your home directory (`~/.fonts.conf`) and paste this in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
   <fontconfig>
      <match target="font">
         <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
         </edit>
      </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for! I played a lot with this file, with 'antialias', 'hinting', 'hintstyle', 'rgba' and 'lcdfilter' options, and nothing helped. 'autohint' did it! Just a note: you must have rgba=none for autohint to work correctly. Seems like autohint is enabled by default in Fedora, but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: +1. Insane that this isn't surfaced in the font preferences in some way.

Comment: Sad reflection on the GNOME philosophy that you even have to ask this question.

Comment: @Juliano Auto-hinting works correctly with sub-pixel rendering, so there is no need for rgba=none.

Comment: @Adam: Are you talking about now or about when this question was asked, back in 2009 (Ubuntu 9.04)?

Comment: Now, I don't know how it was before.

Comment: I'm using gnome on Debian 8 and doing this + restarting worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As John said it, the `~/.fonts.conf` file is useful to tweak your font configuration.

I eventually figured out how it works after reading this article :

http://www.kilobitspersecond.com/2009/04/17/ubuntu-font-hinting-you-a-cautionary-tale/

Answer (score 1):

Although not directly repsonsive to OP, the answer I came here looking for, and which would have saved me about 60 minutes was:

**Don't forget to try turning down your monitor sharpness**.

In Windows, I'd used its font-adjustment tool which somehow compensated for my monitor's overly-high sharpness setting. Switching to Ubuntu with the same monitor, I was like "bleagh why does everything look awful".  All fonts looked terrible, and also made the color depth look low.  Only after trying a wide variety of options, mostly within Ubuntu, did I just start trying every setting on my monitor, and reducing sharpness to zero that solved it.

Comment: thx a million, I was about to tinker a lot but resetting sharpness in OSD to default solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Ubuntu allows changing these settings via Preferences > Appearance > Fonts > Details

I find Medium hinting to be the most pleasing on my LCD screen.

Comment: Yes, the hinting option is already known. The "autohint" option, as mentioned by John T, is the option that is missing in that dialog, including in the latest version of Ubuntu.