# Monaco font has no anti-aliasing effect when the size is smaller than 12

Tags: linux, fonts

I want to set my editor's font as Monaco-11, but it has no anti-aliasing effect. And when I set it to Monaco-12, anti-aliasing effect works. How can I make it also work for Monaco-11? I'm using Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that anti-aliasing is deliberately disabled for small font sizes. This is often done because at small sizes anti-aliasing makes fonts unreadably blurry.

You can probably configure this behaviour. I believe on Ubuntu this is controlled via [Fontconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig). Fontconfig has configuration files in the standard places (/etc/fonts, and ~/.fonts.conf). See the [user manual](http://fontconfig.org/fontconfig-user.html) for details.

You probably want to add `edit` commands to enable anti-aliasing. See e.g. [this blog entry](http://www.drquincy.com/blog/get-smoother-anti-aliasing-on-ubuntu/). You may have to experiment a bit...

*Edit:*

Also see [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/8824/bad-font-anti-aliasing-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 6):

Use older [monaco font](http://www.gringod.com/wp-upload/MONACO.TTF) instead of [the latest one](http://www.gringod.com/wp-upload/software/Fonts/Monaco_Linux.ttf) solved this issue for me.