# How to easily make a screenshot like these (partial enlargement)?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, fedora, screenshot, image-editing

I need to make some screenshots like the images in the following questions & wikipedia pages.

- [Bad font anti-aliasing in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/8824/bad-font-anti-aliasing-in-ubuntu)
- [Who provides the Internet service to Internet Service Providers (ISPs)?](https://superuser.com/questions/399300/who-provides-the-internet-service-to-internet-service-providers-isps) ([Internet map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Internet_map_1024.jpg), Wikipedia)
- [Pixel example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pixel-example.png) (Wikipedia)

Currently, I'm using [picpick](http://www.picpick.org) (for screenshot) and [GIMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-win) (for image editing) on Windows XP, gnome-screenshot and [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) on Fedora 18 (GNOME3 fallback mode). Without a proper tool I have to take several steps to make a final screenshot.

1. Capture original screenshot, save as file1.png
2. Using image editor or image viewer to zoom out file1.png
3. Capture the zoomed screenshot to file2.png
4. Open file2.png with same image editor, and do the following

   1. Draw borders carefully on both original and enlarged image, to make sure 2 borders are matched. (The borders of image in ”[Bad font anti-aliasing in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/8824/bad-font-anti-aliasing-in-ubuntu)“ are not matched, so I guess it's drew by hand too)
   2. Cut the enlarged image with it's border (part of file2.png), and paste into file1.png
   3. Draw the projection lines
5. The final screenshot (there's a transparent character "a" after rgb)

   [image: rgba anti-aliasing example]

It took me more than 7 minutes to make this example screenshot using gnome-screenshot & GIMP, most of the time are costed by selecting rectangles and drawing borders and lines. So I'm wondering is there an image editor, which can easily

- Select rectangle area (optionally, combining <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or<kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select square area)
- Display enlargement inside the same image (better in a different layer)
- And have options to draw borders and projection lines

Comment: You can make a macro to do that on GIMP, or crate an `action` on Photoshop - Photoshop `action`s are just macros with a different name.

Comment: @martineau, thanks, but photoshop isn't free according the correction information. i prefer freeware.